# Debugging screen returns the HTML screen instead of my file

Tags: python, html, flask, file-upload

I made a screen to upload excel files using flask. I wanted to check if my data is being pushed in the correct way, so I raised an exception and tried calling the variable f ( where I stored my file). But it returns the format of my HTML.
Here's the error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs0JO.png)

and I have used following code to call my file:

```
f = request.files["file"]
```

HTML for to choose the file and the upload button:
#Uploading the file:

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class=" form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- file upload start-->
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3 tip-container1" data-trigger="manual"
                                        data-content="Click and browse to select the file with the configuration data"
                                        data-placement="bottom">

                                        <div class="custom-file">
                                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file" />
                                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose
                                                file</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

#Upload Button
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <div class="text-right">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary tip-container1" data-trigger="manual"
                                data-content="Click here to upload the selected data and view the results"
                                data-placement="bottom" name="myButton"
                                style="background-color:grey; width:10%; border-color:grey" type="submit"
                                value="Upload">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: For debugging you should use a debugger like pdb. It is not so difficult. I created a 5 min introduction for PythonIreland https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8

Comment: This worked thanks